# How to make proper design/architecture of partially reusable algorithm?

Tags: c++, c, architecture, computer-vision

I am very sorry for the long explanation, but it is required for proper understanding.

I am working on computer vision algorithms for industrial tasks. Computer vision algorithms tend to be very complicate. Usually they involve calls for dozens (at the very least) of simpler algorithms (that are not simple either). Those calls form certain hierarchy: bigger tasks call some smaller ones, which in turn call even smaller ones, and so on.

Let’s take for example typical computer vision task: find object in image under certain conditions. This is a task that should be performed in dozens of different applications. Each application has its own set of conditions and thus it is impossible to create single algorithm that works for all of them. But they are pretty similar. Usually it is enough to replace one or two lower level functions. For example: use different method for detection of points of interest in image.

And here comes a problem: for each new application I had to copy whole code from one of the existing applications and adapt relevant parts, which is a bad practice. I am trying to eliminate those duplications by creating system of algorithms that can be used in all application without changing the code itself. Here is the list of issues system had to deal with (at least the ones I identified so far):

1) Arguments provided to main algorithm should be able to set the 'algorithmic flow' inside the system, i.e. they determine what lower level algorithms are used and how

2) Different sub-algorithms that perform same task may require different inputs. One may need an array of ints, another requires pair of double, and so on... Algorithms on the higher level should be oblivious to replacement of one sub-algorithm with another. That means they should not be aware of what arguments they receive and pass down to sub-algorithms. Same true for output of sub-algorithm. It may vary if different combination of sub-algorithms is used

3) The system must be extendable. If new sub-algorithm became available (for example: yet another way to find points of interest) the system should be able to call it. I understand that changes might be unavoidable at this point, but I would like to keep them at minimum. And in any case the system should be able to work at the same way with previous sets of arguments.

4) System must be debuggable. End user of the system should have reasonable way to dump debug information about the 'algorithmic flow' in his system, so that algorithm developer will be able to recreate the situation. It is not that trivial considering requirement (3).

5) There should be reasonable way to make sanity check for the flow of algorithms.

6) I am not going to throw exceptions but there should be reasonable way to return success / fail status of each algorithm. Again it is not easy because of requirement (3).

7) This one is more 'good to have' rather than 'must have', but it may be important. Some calculations may be performed by multiple sub-algorithms. For example calculation of gradients in image may (or may not) be required for multiple different tasks. It is good to have an option to store results of those calculations in order to reuse them later.

I created some kind of solution to this but it is far from being good. Do you have any recommendations about how this should be done?

Used language: C++

Thanks you

Comment: This is not the right place to ask such questions :)

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to give a useful answer to this without knowing all the dirty details. Obviously there's some kind of polymorphism involved, but where and how isn't going to be obvious. Also somehow the algorithms need to be heavily encapsulated classes, so that the parameters they use are only known to themselves... exactly how, there's no telling with what's mentioned here. It's easy to toss out some buzzword "design pattern", but that's not going to be helpful without knowing the system details.

Comment: @Lundin, of course I would like to see some code examples, but those buzzwords are also quite useful for me. All my experience is in functional programming. So when I had to design the system I was in loss. I don't know where to start. Having a name of an article that I should read is a good starting point.

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov If you have never worked with OOP before, you aren't going to be able to make a good design for this. Program design is perhaps the part of programming that needs the most experience. There is no way to fully learn program design through books, because books are always discussing ideal conditions in a perfect world where specifications never change and programs never evolve in unexpected directions. You'll need to spend many years as a professional programmer before you will be able to do a decent program design. Hire an experienced consultant for this, if that's an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use some tried and true design patterns.

Use a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to represent an algorithm that you may wish to swap out for alternatives.

Use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) to instantiate different algorithm (strategy) instances based on some input parameter or runtime context - I'm a fan of the [prototype factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) where you have "inert" instances of each object in some lookup table, and based on a key you pass in you can request a clone of the one needed. I like it mainly because it's easiest to extend - you can even add new configured prototype instances to such a factory at runtime.

Note that the same "strategy" model does not have to serve for everything - it sounds like you might have some higher-level/fuzzy operations which then assemble or chain together low-level/detailed operations. The high level operations could be one type of abstract object while the detailed algorithms are the more concrete strategy instances.

As far as the inputs to the various algorithms, if it varies a lot from algorithm to algorithm you could use an extensible object like a dictionary for parameters so that each algorithm can use just the parameters it needs and ignore the others for an operation. If the dictionary is modifiable during the operation this would also permit upstream algorithms to add parameters for downstream algorithms. Key-value pairs are pretty easy to dump to a log or view in a debugger.

If each strategy instance has a unique semantic identifier you could easily debug the algorithms that get instantiated and chained together. (I use an audio DSP library that has a function to dump a description of the whole chain of configured audio processors, it's very handy).

If you use a system with strategy patterns and extensible parameters you should also be able to segregate shared algorithms from application-specific algorithms, but still have the same basic framework for instantiating and running them.

hth

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are a competent OO programmer with good domain knowledge, and your problem is more about a higher level of organisation of software components (implementing algorithms) than OO generally provides.

The patterns mentioned by @orpheist make perfect sense. Consider them. They will not solve all the problems you list. You should also consider the following.

- In what form will the data be for algorithms to access?
- Will you need adapters to connect one component to another?
- Do you pass the data to the component or the component to the data?
- Do you want to assemble a pipeline or group of components to build higher ones, which can then be applied to the data?
- Do you need a language (XML, DSL) to express connections and to allow for easy experimentation?
- Is performance a dominant issue already, or can you afford more interpretive techniques at this stage?

It think you need to refine some of your questions and provide some more concrete specifics. I also think your questions would be a better fit on programmers.stackexchange than here.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider those as well.